# Hazel bash script or Applescript to sum numbers in txt file

Tags: bash, sed, awk, applescript

Thanks in advance for any advice you have to share.

I have been trying to write a script into Hazel to sum the numbers in a text file. I don't have much experience and have tried a lot of different solutions in both bash and Applescript without any results.

Here is an example text file from which I would like to add the numbers preceded by ": $"

```
**15.44.04**

Art materials
: $9

Transport
: $4.50

**15.44.21**

Art materials
: $18

Art materials
: $25

Food
: $11.50

**20.03.53**

Miscellaneous
: $20

**20.04.02**

Food
: $10
```

I woiuld like to append the text "**Total: " with the sum of the values to the end of the file.

Is something like this possible using bash or Applescript?

Thanks again,

Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the script with Hazel, you can keep the shell as `/bin/sh` and use `$1` to refer to the file being processed:

```
awk -F\$ '{x+=$NF}END{print "\n**Total: $"x}' "$1" >> "$1"
```

The script above is only meant to be used with files that don't already have a `**Total` line at the end. This would replace an existing `**Total` line:

```
t=$(sed '/^\*\*Total: /d' "$1")
awk -F\$ '{s+=$NF}1;END{print "\n**Total: $"s}' <<< "$t" > "$1"
```

`sed /pattern/d` deletes lines. If the text after the sed command ends with two linefeeds, `$()` removes both of them. `awk -F\$` sets the field separator, like `BEGIN{FS="$"}`. `$NF` (number of fields) is the value of the last field.

Answer (score 3):

this awk one-liner should do :

```
 awk -F'$' '{x+=$2+0}7;END{print "Total: "x}' file
```

it prints the whole file, and add a line

```
Total: 98
```

at the end.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I have put this into Hazel but it is still returning an error: awk -F'$' '{x+=$2+0}7;END{print "Total: "x}' ARGV[1] Where Hazel refers to the file being processed as ARGV[1]. I have set the shell to /usr/bin/awk, but is there anything else I am missing? Do I need code before/after that line? Thanks again, Rob